# Put destination file exactly where source file was found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

How can someone put the destination file exactly where the source file was found via the 'files' utility.  I just want the file "extras.min.js" to be exactly where grunt found extras.js

my code thus far:

```
  uglify: {
    mytask: {
      files: {
        '_core/js/app.min.js': ['_build/.tmp/templates.js', '_core/js/app.js'],
        'main.min.js': './**/bonus_games/main.js'
      }
    }
  },
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it takes more than one step. The idea is uglify > delete source > move uglified to where source was. You can do this using uglify, [clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean), and [copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

the following syntax works and generate files with different names beside src file

```
  uglify: {
    mytask: {
      files: {
          {src: ['_build/.tmp/templates.js', '_core/js/slot.js'], dest: '_core/js/slot.min.js'},
          {src: '**/bonus_games/main.js', ext: '.min.js', expand: true}
      }
    }
  },
```